# google drive API v3 for name current version

Tags: java, google-drive-api

Is there a way to set a name to the current version of a file in google drive? I am unable to find the method to do this in the Revision class.

We can do this in UI, "File -> Version History -> Name Current Version". Any pointers on how to accomplish this using API.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.
I suspect that this is a Drive-UI only feature and that the Drive-UI app is using appProperties to store a map of `revisionId:name`

If that is the case, then the feature is not available through the API.